# Iterative/chained transitions along line graph with discrete points and delay

Tags: javascript, select, d3.js, transition

I created a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cleb/71je4q8w/#&togetherjs=gmkTz1bVop).

I do have a graph - in this case a sine wave - and want to move a circle along this line (triggered by a click event), stop at certain x and y value pairs that are on this graph and then move on to the last point of the graph  from where it jumps to the first again (ideally this should go on until I press a stop button).

My current problem is that the circle only moves horizontally but not in the ordinate direction and also the delay is visible only once (in the very beginning).

The relevant code is this one (the entire running example can be found in the link above):

Creation of the circle:

```
// the circle I want to move along the graph
  var circle = svg.append("circle")
                .attr("id", "concindi")
                .attr("cx", x_scale(xval[0]))
                .attr("cy", y_scale(yval[0]))
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (0) + "," + (-1 * padding + 15) + ")")
                .attr("r", 6)
                .style("fill", 'red');
```

The moving process:

```
var coordinates = d3.zip(xval, yval);

svg.select("#concindi").on("click", function() {

    coordinates.forEach(function(ci, indi){
      //console.log(ci[1] + ": " + indi);
      //console.log(coordinates[indi+1][1] + ": " + indi);
      if (indi < (coordinates.length - 1)){
        //console.log(coordinates[indi+1][1] + ": " + indi);
        console.log(coordinates[indi + 1][0]);
        console.log(coordinates[indi + 1][1]);
        d3.select("#concindi")
          .transition()
          .delay(2000)
          .duration(5000)
          .ease("linear")
          .attr("cx", x_scale(coordinates[indi + 1][0]))
          .attr("cy", y_scale(coordinates[indi + 1][1]));
      }

    });
```

I am pretty sure that I use the loop in a wrong manner. The idea is to start at the first x/y pair, then move to the next one (which takes 5s), wait there for 2s and move on to the next and so on. Currently, the delay is only visible initially and then it just moves horizontally.

How would this be done correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use Bostock's [translateAlong](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868) function?

```
function translateAlong(path) {
    var l = path.getTotalLength();
    return function(d, i, a) {
        return function(t) {
            var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
            return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
        };
    };
}
```

Here is the demo:

```js
// function to generate some data
function get_sin_val(value) {
  return 30 * Math.sin(value * 0.25) + 35;
}

var width = 400;
var height = 200;
var padding = 50;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var xrange_min = 0;
var xrange_max = 50;

var yrange_min = 0;
var yrange_max = 100;

var x_scale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([xrange_min, xrange_max])
  .range([padding, width - padding * 2]);

var y_scale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([yrange_min, yrange_max])
  .range([height - padding, padding]);

// create the data
var xval = d3.range(xrange_min, xrange_max, 1);
var yval = xval.map(get_sin_val);

// just for convenience
var coordinates = d3.zip(xval, yval);

//defining line graph
var lines = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x_scale(d[0]);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y_scale(d[1]);
  })
  .interpolate("linear");

//draw graph
var sin_graph = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", lines(coordinates))
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none");

// the circle I want to move along the graph
var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("id", "concindi")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (x_scale(xval[0])) + "," + (y_scale(yval[0])) + ")")
  .attr("r", 6)
  .style("fill", 'red');

svg.select("#concindi").on("click", function() {
  d3.select(this).transition()
    .duration(5000)
    .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(sin_graph.node()));

});

// Returns an attrTween for translating along the specified path element.
function translateAlong(path) {
  var l = path.getTotalLength();
  return function(d, i, a) {
    return function(t) {
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
      return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
    };
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

You have to understand that `forEach` will loop to the end of the array almost instantaneously. Thus, you cannot make the circle jumping to one coordinate to the other with your approach right now (thus, unfortunately, you are correct here:*"I am pretty sure that I use the loop in a wrong manner"*).

If you want to add the 2s waiting period between one point and another, the best idea is chaining the transitions. Something like this (I'm reducing the delay and the duration times in the demo, so we can better see the effect):

```
var counter = 0;
transit();
function transit() {
    counter++;
    d3.select(that).transition()
        .delay(500)
        .duration(500)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (x_scale(coordinates[counter][0])) 
            + "," + (y_scale(coordinates[counter][1])) + ")")
        .each("end", transit);
}
```

Here is the demo:

```js
// function to generate some data
function get_sin_val(value) {
  return 30 * Math.sin(value * 0.25) + 35;
}

var width = 400;
var height = 200;
var padding = 50;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var xrange_min = 0;
var xrange_max = 50;

var yrange_min = 0;
var yrange_max = 100;

var x_scale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([xrange_min, xrange_max])
  .range([padding, width - padding * 2]);

var y_scale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([yrange_min, yrange_max])
  .range([height - padding, padding]);

// create the data
var xval = d3.range(xrange_min, xrange_max, 1);
var yval = xval.map(get_sin_val);

// just for convenience
var coordinates = d3.zip(xval, yval);

//defining line graph
var lines = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x_scale(d[0]);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y_scale(d[1]);
  })
  .interpolate("linear");

//draw graph
var sin_graph = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", lines(coordinates))
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none");

// the circle I want to move along the graph
var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("id", "concindi")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (x_scale(xval[0])) + "," + (y_scale(yval[0])) + ")")
  .attr("r", 6)
  .style("fill", 'red');

svg.select("#concindi").on("click", function() {
  var counter = 0;
  var that = this;
transit();
  function transit() {
    counter++;
    d3.select(that).transition()
      .delay(500)
      .duration(500)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (x_scale(coordinates[counter][0])) + "," + (y_scale(coordinates[counter][1])) + ")")
      .each("end", transit);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that already looks nice (upvoted). Few more questions: As `forEach` does not work, would there be another loop available that could do that? In your second example, `counter` can be undefined; would it be difficult to set `counter` back to 0 once the end of the graph is reached so that it starts from the beginning?!

Comment: Regarding the first example, the thing is, that I want to use the values in `coordinates` in a different part of the svg as well; if I use the approach you showed, I also receive coordinates which are not stored in `coordinates` which would lead to problems with the other part of the code.

Comment: All loops in javascript run to the end immediately. The example with `counter` is just that, a general example: you'll have to modify it according to your needs. Here is a very simple `if` that sets counter back to zero: https://jsfiddle.net/8v58e1wz/

Comment: Ok, that should get me started with my actual example; if I run into issues, I will open a new question. Thanks a lot for your detailed reply; helps me a lot!